# converting multiple variables into factors using information from .csv in R

Tags: r, csv, lapply, factors

I want to convert several similar variables into factors, but I want to do so in one go rather than individually. Most importantly, I want to achieve this using information from an external .csv file called 'codes.csv' in which I've set out all of the pertinent information to do with the variable, e.g. 'levels' and 'labels.' My data looks like the following:

```
set.seed(1234)

my_data <- data.frame(citation_1 = sample(c(1:7), 10, replace = TRUE),
                      citation_2 = sample(c(1:7), 10, replace = TRUE),
                      citation_3 = sample(c(1:7), 10, replace = TRUE))

my_data
```

Of course, I could do the following for each variable...

```
codes <- read.csv("codes.csv", header = FALSE)

my_data$citation_1 <- factor(my_data$citation_1,
                             levels = codes[, 1],
                             labels = codes[, 2])
```

But there's gotta be a more efficient method; I've tried the following code and variations thereof:

```
citations <- c("citation_1", "citation_2", "citation_3")

my_data[citations] <- lapply(my_data[citations], factor,
                             levels = codes[, 1],
                             labels = codes[, 2])
```

My 'codes.csv' file looks like the following ('levels' are listed in the first column of this mock file; 'labels' in the second):

```
1 dismissed
2 acquitted by court
3 acquitted by jury
4 convicted/plea of guilty
5 convicted/plea of nolo contendere
6 convicted by court
7 convicted by jury
```

(I'd attach the above .csv file but I don't think I can.) Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result making a small change to `lapply`. We will use an anonymous function to apply `factor` to each column.

```
  my_data[citations] <- lapply(my_data[citations], function(each_column){
    factor(each_column,
           levels = codes[, 1],
           labels = codes[, 2])
  })
```

You can do this reading directly the `codes.csv` inside `lapply`, if you desire so.

```
  my_data[citations] <- lapply(my_data, function(each_column) {
    factor(each_column,
           levels = read.csv("codes.csv")[, 1],
           labels = read.csv("codes.csv")[, 2])
  })
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much for the prompt reply - you've saved me hours mindlessly typing the same code over and over...

Comment: Ahh...I just clicked on the green arrow if that's what you mean; I'm a bit of a newbie 'round these parts. Thanks again.